# Identifying Consecutive Sequences of Data and Counting their Lengths

Tags: python, function, datetime, pandas, dataframe

I am working with a DataFrame where each row observation has an ordinal datetime object attached to it. I've written a function that I believe looks through my DataFrame and identifies consecutively occurring days and the length of run of these consecutively occurring days with the following code:

```
 def consecutiveCount(df):
    df= df.copy()
    cond1 = df['DATE_INT'].shift(-1) - df['DATE_INT'] == 1
    cond2 = df['DATE_INT'].shift(1) - df['DATE_INT'] == -1

    cond3 = df['DATE_INT'].shift(-2) - df['DATE_INT'] == 2            
    cond4 = df['DATE_INT'].shift(2) - df['DATE_INT'] == -2
```

Now I continue making these conditions in the same fashion until the point:

```
    cond55 = df['DATE_INT'].shift(-28) - df['DATE_INT'] == 28            
    cond56 = df['DATE_INT'].shift(28) - df['DATE_INT'] == -28

    cond57 = df['DATE_INT'].shift(-29) - df['DATE_INT'] == 29            
    cond58 = df['DATE_INT'].shift(29) - df['DATE_INT'] == -29
```

I then write the length of the 'run' of days in a column variable with the following code:

```
    df.loc[cond1 | cond2, 'CONSECUTIVE_COUNT'] = 2
    df.loc[cond3 | cond4, 'CONSECUTIVE_COUNT'] = 3
```

again I continue until I reach 'runs' of days of length 30.

```
    df.loc[cond55 | cond56, 'CONSECUTIVE_COUNT'] = 29
    df.loc[cond57 | cond58, 'CONSECUTIVE_COUNT'] = 30
```

Finally I apply the function to particular groups of my DataFrame as follows:

```
    df1 = df.groupby(['COUNTY_GEOID_YEAR','TEMPBIN']).apply(consecutiveCount)
```

I am sure there are much more efficient ways to write this code. I've identified the bottle neck in my script is when applying the function by printing various strings throughout my script.

Any help on writing the function in a more efficient manner or how to speed up applying the function would be great! Please let me know if I can provide anymore info.

EDIT: As @DSM pointed out my code is not accurately counting the length of consecutive runs of days properly. His solution did so accurately for me!

Comment: Your current code seems like it would say that a DATE_INT column of [1,2,3,4] (for the same COUNTY_GEOID_YEAR and TEMPBIN) would have consecutive counts of [4,3,3,4].  I'm not sure I get the logic there.

Comment: oh - your right, thanks for pointing that out. Thats not what I want at all - I will try implementing your solution below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can you can use the shift-compare-cumsum pattern after applying your groupby, and then do a transform.

Assuming that your data looks something like this (simplifying a bit)

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"GEOID_YEAR": [2000]*10 + [2001]*4, "TEMPBIN": [1]*14,
                   "DATE_INT": [1,2,3,4,6,7,9,10,11,14] + list(range(14,18)),
                   "OTHER_COL": [2]*14})
```

or

```
    DATE_INT  GEOID_YEAR  OTHER_COL  TEMPBIN
0          1        2000          2        1
1          2        2000          2        1
2          3        2000          2        1
3          4        2000          2        1
4          6        2000          2        1
5          7        2000          2        1
6          9        2000          2        1
7         10        2000          2        1
8         11        2000          2        1
9         14        2000          2        1
10        14        2001          2        1
11        15        2001          2        1
12        16        2001          2        1
13        17        2001          2        1
```

then

```
df["cons_id"] = df.groupby(["GEOID_YEAR", "TEMPBIN"])["DATE_INT"].apply(
    lambda x: (x != x.shift() + 1).cumsum())
df["cons_count"] = (df.groupby(["GEOID_YEAR", "TEMPBIN", "cons_id"])
                    ["cons_id"].transform("count"))
```

gives us

```
In [78]: df
Out[78]: 
    DATE_INT  GEOID_YEAR  OTHER_COL  TEMPBIN  cons_id  cons_count
0          1        2000          2        1        1           4
1          2        2000          2        1        1           4
2          3        2000          2        1        1           4
3          4        2000          2        1        1           4
4          6        2000          2        1        2           2
5          7        2000          2        1        2           2
6          9        2000          2        1        3           3
7         10        2000          2        1        3           3
8         11        2000          2        1        3           3
9         14        2000          2        1        4           1
10        14        2001          2        1        1           4
11        15        2001          2        1        1           4
12        16        2001          2        1        1           4
13        17        2001          2        1        1           4
```

Comment: Applying the solution gave me a ValueError caused by the second groupby in creating 'cons_count'. Modifying the code to     df.groupby(['COUNTY_GEOID_YEAR','TEMPBIN'])['cons_id'].transform('count') did the trick. Just verifying now that this results in what I wanted. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @Justin: ah, sorry, yeah -- I assumed there were no other columns.  I'll modify.